# Formula gives wrong output

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use this:

```
=IF(LEFT(G5,1)=0,0,1)
```

In `G5` there is `0.6`.

In this formula left of `G5` is '0' till 1 digit, so the output should be '0', but it gives me '1'.

Can anybody say why?

Comment: Are you testing values smaller than unit? Consider using `=IF(AND(G5>=0, G5<1), 0, 1)` or condensed `=(G5>=0)*(G5<1)`.

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like, or what other results you want, but a `ROUNDDOWN` formula might be appropriate. If possible, it's good to use numeric funtions on numbers and text numbers on text.

Answer (score 6):

Consider:

**=IF(LEFT(G5,1)="0",0,1)**

Answer (score 3):

The result of LEFT, MID, RIGHT is always a text string and "0" does not equal 0, hence test results in FALSE.

Answer (score 3):

That is because the LEFT function is a `TEXT` function, and converts any numbers passed to it to text, like wise it returns a `TEXT` value. See example below for better explanation

[image]

so change your formula to:

```
=IF(LEFT(G5,1)="0",0,1)
```

for what you desire